# Rearranging arrays in Perl

Tags: arrays, perl

Apologies for a simple question, but I'm very new to Perl!
I have an array called @input which has the following data (note that the size of @input will not always be the same):

```
[0]  20004 11189 20207
[1]  12345 1234 123 12 1
```

I would like to create a new array called @elements which rearranges the data to be:

```
[0] 20004
[1] 11189
[2] 20207
[3] 12345
[4] 1234
[5] 123
[6] 12
[7] 1
```

Thanks!

Comment: When you say `[0]  20004 11189 20207`, do you mean that element [0] contains a single string with those values, or that element [0] is itself another array containing three values?  It would be very helpful if you could post the output of the debugger command `x @input`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$tmparr = join(" ", @input);
@elements = split(" ", $tmparr);
```

Does this work?

Edit: **TLP** has provided a **much better** solution in the comment below, `map split, @input`

Comment: Why use a transition variable when its not needed? And join when interpolation does the same thing? `@elements = split ' ', "@input"`

Comment: Why use an argument to `split` when it's not needed? `@input = map { split } @input`.

Comment: @davorg Why use brackets for map when it's not needed? `map split, @input`. =)

Answer (score 2):

Well, either it's a one-dimensional array that needs splitting, or a two-dimensional that needs flattening. So, here's a sub for each task.

```
use v5.10;
use strict;
use warnings;

my @input1 = ("20004 11189 20207", "12345 1234 123 12 1");
my @input2 = ([qw"20004 11189 20207"], [qw"12345 1234 123 12 1"]);

sub one_dim { # Simple extract digits with regex
    return map /\d+/g, @_;
    # return map split, @_;  # same thing, but with split
}
sub two_dim { # Simple expand array ref
    return map @$_, @_;
}

my @new = one_dim(@input1);
say for @new;
@new = two_dim(@input2);
say for @new;
```

Answer (score 1):

More efficient than Jon's answer:

```
@output = map { split / / } @input;
```

Comment: `@output = map split, @input`

Comment: @TLP please post your solution as an answer

Comment: @Borodin I have posted an answer. Using `split` is dolmen's answer, I used `/\d+/g`, which basically does the same thing.